# Rails 2.3.11 Oauth2 SSL Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, oauth-2.0

I've seen questions similar to this one but the suggested solution didnt seem to work.

I'm trying to perform oauth, using [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/), when im trying to get the access_token, I get the following error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I'm using:

```
rails 2.3.11
faraday 0.8.1
oauth2 0.8.0
```

and I'm running on Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Development, staging and production are linux based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in development.rb

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

This will solve your issues.

Comment: Avi, while this will make the error go away, this is *NOT* a solution. In fact, this is a terrible piece of advice. This will render the whole SSL pointless. The proper way is to use a proper certificate bundle. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199660/why-is-ruby-unable-to-verify-an-ssl-certificate

Comment: This is definitely not a production solution, this is a solution for development only and I would not say this is ANY sort of solution if the guy was not using windows.

it's a dev machine and it's windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The *proper* solution would be to initialize the OAuth::Client with a proper certificate bundle (it can be taken from a curl distribution, for instance).

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, ssl: {ca_file: "/path/to/ca-bundle.crt"})
```