# How can i use trust and key store into cacerts in ruby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

As java security has cacerts file and provide to store trust and key. is ruby provide same security as java provide.let me know any ideas to do create secure connection to websocket server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

I understand you're coming from the Java world. However, it's difficult to tell what exactly you are needing.

If you are wondering about how TLS/SSL certificates are handled in Ruby, please check the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238221/2658159.

If you are wondering about how the server should be set up (you write "create secure connection to websocket..."), that is not a Ruby-specific question. You'll want to think about posting another question, with the appropriate tags, and a clear, reproducible example of the specific question in mind.